# Making more than one primary key in hsqldb

Tags: hsqldb

I have a mssql-server query which contains something similar to the query like below;

```
CONSTRAINT PK_Application PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ApplicationName, ApplicationID),
CONSTRAINT IX_Application UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (ApplicationParentID)
```

I tried writing like below in hsqldb,

```
CONSTRAINT PK_Application PRIMARY KEY(ApplicationName, ApplicationID),
CONSTRAINT IX_Application PRIMARY KEY(ApplicationParentID)
```

but, i get error:

> primary key already exist

Is there anyway to achieve the same functionality in `hsqldb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with the `UNIQUE` keyword and looks like it works!

```
CONSTRAINT PK_Application PRIMARY KEY(ApplicationName, ApplicationID),
CONSTRAINT IX_Application UNIQUE(ApplicationParentID)
```

I get no more errors if i write like above.